# Recaptcha for .NET Does Not Work in AJAX Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, captcha, recaptcha

I want to use 'Recaptcha for .NET' in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application. I did instructions [here](http://recaptchanet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20Use%20Recaptcha%20in%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%20Web%20Application&referringTitle=Documentation). I use AJAX request to login the user through the following script:

```
$(".@loginGuid button[type=button]").click(function () {
      var wrapper = $(this).parents(".@loginGuid");
      wrapper.find(".has-error").removeClass("has-error");
      var dto = {
        Valid: true,
        UserName: wrapper.find(".user-name").val(),
        Password: wrapper.find(".password").val(),
        Remember: wrapper.find(".remember").is(":checked"),
      };

      if (!validateUserName(dto.UserName)) {
        dto.Valid = false;
        wrapper.find(".user-name").addClass("has-error");
      }
      if (dto.Password.length < 6) {
        dto.Valid = false;
        wrapper.find(".password").addClass("has-error");
      }

      if (dto.Valid) {

        $.ajax({
          url: "/Account/AjaxLogin",
          type: "post",
          data: JSON.stringify(dto),
          context: dto,
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
          cache: false,
          statusCode: {
            404: function () {
              alert("page not found");
            },
            200: function () {
            }
          }
        }).done(function (result) {
          if (result) {
            if (result.Succeed) {
              window.location.reload();
            } else {
              $.map(result.Messages, function (item, index) {
                alert(item);
              });
            }
          }
        }).fail(function () {
        }).always(function () {

        });
      }
      return false;
    });
```

Here is my action method:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult AjaxLogin(string username, string password, bool remember)
    {
        ScriptResult scriptResult = new ScriptResult() { Succeed = true };

        RecaptchaVerificationHelper recaptchaHelper = this.GetRecaptchaVerificationHelper();
        RecaptchaVerificationResult recaptchaResult = recaptchaHelper.VerifyRecaptchaResponse();
        if (recaptchaResult != RecaptchaVerificationResult.Success)
        {
            scriptResult.Messages.Add("Incorrect captcha answer.");
            scriptResult.Succeed = false;
        }
        else
        {
            var user = UserManager.Find(username, password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                user.UserName = user.UserName.ToLower();
                SignIn(user, remember);
            }
            else
            {
                scriptResult.Messages.Add(LocalizeHelper.GetLocalizeString("Invalid username or password."));
                scriptResult.Succeed = false;
            }
        }

        return Json(scriptResult);
    }
```

When I fill out the login form(username, password and captcha fields) and click the login button, then I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Recaptcha.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Recaptcha challenge field cannot be empty.

Comment: Step through the code with the debugger until it fails. But I don't see that you're passing any captcha input with the AJAX request. You only pass the `dto` values and that matches the error message: `Recaptcha challenge field cannot be empty`.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked assumed a standard form post so the Recaptcha form values are likely pulled from `Request.Form["x"]` where x is a particular form field from the Recaptcha control. *You are doing an AJAX request so you will need to pass these values explicitly yourself.*

If you examine the html for the rendered Recaptcha control you will see two input fields.

```
<input id="recaptcha_challenge_field" ... />
<input id="recaptcha_response_field" ... />
```

These values will need to be passed in your AJAX request so your javascript becomes:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Account/AjaxLogin",
    type: "post",
    data: {
        recaptcha_challenge_field: $("#recaptcha_challenge_field").val(),
        recaptcha_response_field: $("#recaptcah_response_field").val(),
        ...
    }
})
```

Your controller action signature does not change

```
public ActionResult AjaxLogin(string username, string password, bool remember)
```

And you can verify the values are passed if you inspect inside your controller action

```
var challenge = Request.Form["recaptcha_challenge_field"];
var answer = Request.Form["recaptcha_response_field"];
```

From the actual [source code](http://recaptchanet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/Recaptcha.Web/RecaptchaVerificationHelper.cs) we see that the RecaptchaVerificationHelper's values are taken from the Request:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
...
this._Challenge = request.Form["recaptcha_challenge_field"];
this.Response = request.Form["recaptcha_response_field"];
```

**You do not need to do anything more than POST the values to your action** then call `recaptchaHelper.VerifyRecaptchaResponse()`. Since you are not doing standard form submission the javascript above will send the values via the AJAX post.

Comment: The method RecaptchaVerificationHelper recaptchaHelper = this.GetRecaptchaVerificationHelper() is working based on a value. I don't know how to tell GetRecaptchaVerificationHelper() method that I provided challenge and answer values.

Comment: @Mohsen I have edited the answer to be more clear about what is needed.